# java cdi область видимости событий

Tags: java, cdi

Есть бины с областю видимости @SessionScoped и @ViewScoped для бинов применяемых в пользовательских сессиях. Создаю бин, который по команде будет генерировать событие, принимаемое пользовательскими бинами.Этот бин имеет область видимости @ApplicationScoped.

```
@ApplicationScoped
@Named
public class Сoordinator implements Serializable {
    @Inject Event<MyEvent> myEventEvent;

    public void fire(){
        myEventEvent.fire(new MyEvent());
    }
}


@Named 
@ViewScoped
public class UsersBean implements Serializable {

 @Inject
 private Сoordinator coordinator;
//...
    public void fire(){
      coordinator.fire();
    }

    void proc(@Observes MyEvent myEvent) {
        System.out.println("test");
    }
}
```

При вызове событие отрабатывает, но только в пределах видимости пользовательского бина от которого был осуществлен вызов метода fire. Я же хочу что бы событие ловили все пользовательские бины.  Возможно ли  это и как это сделать?

(Можно сделать и другими способами, но хочу через механизм CDI event.)